# Create a Customer from a Guest - using MVC3, C#, Entity Framework, Razor Views, SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am adding a function into my program that allows Employees to convert event guest to customers, so they don't have to retype everything.

The one problem I am running into is... The guest has a phone # and rmail in the same table as the rest of their information. Customers have their phone #'s and emails stored in separate one-to-many table.

So during the conversion I need a `CustomerID` to assign to the email & phone number to store it to the tables.

How do I create the customer and retain the `CustomerID` in order to use to assign to the `CustomerEmail` and `CustomerPhone` tables?

I have a ViewModel to handle all the variables.

What do I have to do to the code below to have it assign a `CustomerID` in order to successfully call `SaveChanges()` for `CustomerPhones` && `CustomerEmails`?

```
var customerNew = new Customer
                {
                    CustomerTypeId = customer.CustomerTypeId,
                    FirstName = customer.FirstName,
                    LastName = customer.LastName,
                    FullName = customer.FirstName + " " + customer.LastName,
                    Birthday = customer.Birthday,
                    GenderId = customer.GenderId,
                    CompanyName = customer.CompanyName,
                    UserName = customer.UserName,
                    FavMusicId = customer.FavMusicId,
                    OwnerId = customer.OwnerId
                };

                var phoneNew = new CustomerPhone
                {
                    CustomerId = customer.CustomerId,
                    Number = customer.Number,
                    PhoneTypeId = 5
                };

                var emailNew = new CustomerEmail
                {
                    CustomerId = customer.CustomerId,
                    Email = customer.Email
                };

                db.Customers.AddObject(customerNew);
                db.CustomerPhones.AddObject(phoneNew);
                db.CustomerEmails.AddObject(emailNew);

                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = customer.CustomerId });
```

Thank you,

Tim

**EXTRA Bonus Points:** If you can tell me how to automatically delete the guest from the database after the customer creation, without having to click anything else. :)

Comment: I know you didn't ask for this, but once you have found a solution I strongly suggest using automapper (or another such tool) to take care of the mapping for you. It will do a lot of this stuff by convention and make the code look a lot cleaner...

Comment: I hope you do have a foreign key relation between the `CustomerPhone` and `Customer` tables - right?? (also between `CustomerEmail` and `Customer`) In that case, you could (1) create your customer, (2) add his customer phone and connect the two via the EF association, and (3) create a customer email and again associate that with the main `Customer` object and then let EF do all the work for you....

Comment: @marc_s yes I have all the foreign keys setup, and I am using POCOs for EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set up proper foreign key relationships on the database level, and your EF model has picked them up, you should be able to write:

```
var customerNew = new Customer
                  {
                      // ... set all the properties here
                  }

var phoneNew = new CustomerPhone
            {
                Number = customer.Number,
                PhoneTypeId = 5
            };
customerNew.CustomerPhones.Add(phoneNew);  // add new phone to the association

var emailNew = new CustomerEmail
            {
                Email = customer.Email
            };
customerNew.CustomerEMails.Add(phoneNew);  // add new e-mail to the association

db.Customers.AddObject(customerNew);
db.SaveChanges();
```

and let EF handle all the rest like figuring out the ID's and everything.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I have been working on this all day. I had no Ideal you could just add associations like that. Thank you!

Comment: Would I be able to through in a db.Guests.DeleteObject(guest); in there before the savechanges(); ??? To have it remove the guest from the guest list they are currently on.

Comment: @Timothy Green: yes, definitely - you should be able to (1) add the new customer with his phone(s) and e-mail(s) and (2) delete the old "Guest" entry at the same time, with a single call to `.SaveChanges`

Comment: I take it i should be able to do something similar to remove associations on the DeleteObject() - thank you once again for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sned the guest information (complete) into a stored procedure that creates the new records (customer, phone and email).

EXTRA Bonus Points options

1. Add a delete to the stored procedure - benefit here is you can put this in a transaction
2. Add a trigger that deletes the guest based on the insert into the client table - very effective if everyone is a guest before they are a customer

Point here is you don't have to solve this in MVC alone, since persistence is the real issue, not the user experience.

Comment: How does that get me the CustomerID to insert for the CustomerEmail and CustomerPhone Tables?

Comment: Assuming integer with auto-increment SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY(). There are other ways if not auto created.